# MVC 2. My page jumps to the right when I change my selection in a dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using nested master pages, which may or may not cause the problem here.
My view looks like this;

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="AdminAccountsContent" runat="server">
    <% using (Html.BeginForm())
       {%>
        <h3>Christmas Shutdown Administration</h3>
        <p>Before entering the Christmas shutdown dates, make sure you have entered in the Christmas bank holidays.</p>
        <p>Select the year: <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedYear, Model.YearList)%></p>
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Enter the Christmas Shutdown dates here:</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Day</th>
                    <th>Shutdown?</th>
                </tr>
                <% foreach (var christmasDate in Model.ChristmasShutdownList)
                   { %>
                    <% Html.RenderPartial("ChristmasShutdownSummary", christmasDate); %>
                <% } %>
               <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="3" style="padding-top:20px;">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </fieldset>
    <% } %>
           <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
               $(function () {
                   $("#SelectedYear").change(function () {
                       var year = $("#SelectedYear").val();
                       $("#wholepage").load("/ChristmasShutdown/Create/" + year);
                   });
               });

    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

The drop down list is in the second paragraph.
The div #wholepage is defined in the main master page;

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
    <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/overcast/jquery-ui.css" 
            type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" class="ui-theme" />
<%--    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".datePicker").datepicker({ showOn: 'both', dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page" id="wholepage">

        <div id="header">
            <div id="title">
                <h1>Staff Holiday Planner (SHP)</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="logindisplay">
                <% Html.RenderPartial("LogOnUserControl"); %>
            </div> 

            <div id="menucontainer">
                <% Html.RenderPartial("MenuItems"); %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
            <div id="footer">
            </div>
        </di
```

v>

The nested master page is as follows;

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
<asp:Content ID="TitleContent1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="MainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div id="adminAccounts">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> <% Html.RenderPartial("AdminAccountsMenu"); %></td>
            <td><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="AdminAccountsContent" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table></div>
</asp:Content>
```

So why is it when I change the selection in the drop down list that the page jumps to the right? How do I stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in MVC would cause your page to jump to the right.

This is a javascript or html error.

Are you positive the page isn't jumping because a vertical scrollbar appears and/or disappears?

Comment: It may well be my lack of understanding of HTML and Javascript. I think the DIV with the id wholepage should be the correct container to reload the page with no problems, but it is not turning out that way.

Comment: @arame333 - So ask a different question or edit this one.  The jquery tag is pretty active and you'll probably get help fast if its a jquery related question.

Comment: I now realise the problem was here; <div class="page" id="wholepage">. The page class had a width of 90%. So I put the "wholepage" id on the body element, and now it works.